# how to convert a binary array to .wav with c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing a project in C# which requires me to encrypt a wave file. So, is there a straight forward process to convert a wave file into binary and back? I'll be applying an encryption algorithm on the binary data.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, checkout the [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) methods. Or if the files are too large to fit in memory you could read/write in blocks using a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) to read a binary file, such as WAV file and then another `FileStream` to write the encrypted version back out.

You need to read and write the files in blocks using a byte array.